# Something wrong with my React UseParam & node.js code

Tags: node.js, react-hooks, jsx

I was trying to connect server and client code.
But I have few problems,
[my url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRi02.png)
[my cosole.error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F3BN.png)

I was able to get userid from chrome console, but I can't get any other data from /:userid, (GET http://localhost:8080/profile/Atlantisss 404 (Not Found))

I think there's something wrong with my code, but I cannot catch the problem.

profile.js (server)

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../moongoose/schemas/user");

router.get("/:userid", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const userID = req.params.userid;
        console.log(userID);

        // Retrieve user information based on userId
        const result = await User.findOne({ ID: userID }).lean();
        console.log("looking for userid");

        // Check if the user was found
        if (!result) {
            return res.status(404).send("User not found");
        }

        // Result response
        res.send(result);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        next(e);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is my client code

ProfilePage.jsx (client)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";
import NavBar from "../navbar/NavBar";
import RightBar from "../rightbar/RightBar";
import Menu from "../ui/Menu";
import Follower from "../ui/Follower";
import FollowButton from '../ui/FollowButton';

//css

function ProfilePage() {
    //const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { userid } = useParams();
    const [ profileData, setProfileData ] = useState({});
    

    const endpoint = `/profile/${ userid }`;
    console.log('userid:', userid );

    useEffect(() => {

        const fetchProfileData = async () => {
            try {
                if (!userid) {
                    console.error('userid is undefined');
                    return;
                }
                const response = await fetch(endpoint);
                if (response.ok) {
                    const data = await response.json();
                    setProfileData(data);
                    console.log('Profile Data:', data); // 데이터 출력

                } else {
                    console.error('Failed to fetch profile data', response.status, response.statusText);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        };

        fetchProfileData();
    });

    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <NavBar />
            <MenuContainer>
                <Menu/>
                <Menu />
            </MenuContainer>
            <BGContainer>
                <BlueBox>
                    
                </BlueBox>
                <WhiteBox>
                    <TextWrapper>
                        <Nickname>{profileData.name}</Nickname>
                        <Id>{profileData.ID}</Id>
                        <FollowButton />
                    </TextWrapper>
                    <Follower />
                </WhiteBox>
                <Circle>
                    
                </Circle>
            </BGContainer>
            <RightBar />
        </Wrapper>
    );
}

export default ProfilePage;
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import styled from 'styled-components';
// Pages
import MainPage from './component/page/MainPage';
import PostWritePage from './component/page/PostWritePage';
import PostViewPage from './component/page/PostViewPage';
import SearchPage from "./component/page/SearchPage";
import MorePage from "./component/page/MorePage";
import CommunityPage from "./component/page/CommunityPage";
import ProfilePage from "./component/page/ProfilePage";
import JoinPage from "./component/page/JoinPage";
import LoginPage from "./component/page/LoginPage";

const MainTitleText = styled.p`
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
`;

function App(props) {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <MainTitleText></MainTitleText>
      <Routes>
        <Route index element={<MainPage/>} />
        <Route path="post-write" element={<PostWritePage />} />
        <Route path="post/:postId" element={<PostViewPage />} />
        <Route path="home" element={<MainPage/>} />
        <Route path="search" element={<SearchPage/>} />
        <Route path="community" element={<CommunityPage/>} />
        <Route path="profile/:userid" element={<ProfilePage/>} />
        <Route path="more" element={<MorePage/>} />
        <Route path="join" element={<JoinPage/>} />
        <Route path="login" element={<LoginPage/>} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: your endpoint only is  const response = await fetch(endpoint); ?? that is ok?

Comment: i think this part: should be like this: router.get("/:id", async (req, res, next) => { instead of router.get("/:userid", async (req, res, next) => {

Comment: @rnewed_user here's my endpoint!     const endpoint = `/profile/${ userid }`;

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to advance actions
first you have to get a user

```
const user = await User.findOne({ ID: userID })
```

depend of that we gonna to get lean() if exist user

```
   // Check if the user was found
    if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).send("User not found");
    }

    // Result response
    res.send(user?.lean());
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried but same problem occured.

Comment: @levi why are you using in cappital letter the id? User.findOne({ ID: userID }) maybe it should like this User.findOne({ id: userID })

Comment: or User.findOne({ _id: userID })

Comment: @rnewd_user That's because my mongodb schema includes ID: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, the problem was from the resource.

My paths of resources were totally wrong, and it blocks the website rendering the whole page.

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).